# How do I deallocate memory for allocated class from node on Linked List

Tags: c++, oop, memory-management, linked-list

In my code I've made a list of nodes who carry pointers to dynamically allocated class objects and I can't seem to figure out how to make sure I free the memory upon deletion of a specific node.

```
//create temporary node
node *temp = new node;
//create the pointer to the class
Dog *thisDog = new Dog(age, name);
//set the next pointer to NULL (points to nothing)
temp->next = NULL;
//set first value in list to temp
head = temp;
//set last value to temp
last = temp;
```

Will the destructor within the class object take care of this for me when I delete the node? Or within my node deletion function should I include something such as the following:

```
//delete one element
delete *&thisDog;
delete head;
//set the head and last pointer to NULL, point to nothing
head = NULL;
last = NULL;
```

Here is my node structure:

```
struct node
{
    Dog *thisDog;
    node *next;
};
```

Comment: `delete *&thisDog;` - that alone should be an indicator something has possibly run afoul, as `delete thisDog;` should be sufficient. And was your intention to put `thisDog` somewhere in the list, because that isn't happening in your posted code.

Comment: Update your *question* with relevant content please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly `delete` anything you allocate with `new` (unless you use a smart pointer wrapper, like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`).  You need to `delete` the `node`, and you need to `delete` the `Dog`:

```
node *temp = new node;
...
delete temp;
```

```
Dog *thisDog = new Dog(age, name);
...
delete thisDog;
```

If `node` is meant to own the `Dog` object, then you can add a destructor to `node` to perform that `delete`:

```
struct node
{
    Dog *thisDog;
    node *next;

    node() : thisDog(NULL), next(NULL) {}
    ~node() { delete thisDog; }
};
```

```
node *temp = new node;
node->thisDog = new Dog(age, name);

...

delete node; // calls 'delete thisDog'...
```

Or, you could simply not use `new` at all to allocate the `Dog`:

```
struct node
{
    Dog thisDog;
    node *next;

    node(int age, string name) : thisDog(age, name), next(NULL) {}
};
```

```
node *temp = new node(age, name);

...

delete node; // frees 'thisDog' automatically...
```

And then when you have that all figured out, get rid of your manual linked-list implementation and use [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) instead, let it manage the nodes for you:

```
#include <list>

std::list<Dog> mylist;
```

```
Dog thisDog(age, name);
mylist.push_back(thisDog);
```

```
Dog thisDog(age, name);
mylist.push_front(thisDog);
```

```
mylist.pop_back();
```

```
mylist.pop_front();
```

```
std::list<Dog>::iterator iter = ...; // any method that returns an iterator to a list element
mylist.erase(iter);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what i was looking for. And I was originally trying to not allocate anything but this program was more of a practice with memory allocation, memory leaks for myself.